# Xcode, OS X app: Can I record the speaker's audio output?

Tags: xcode, macos, audio, audio-recording, mac-app-store

Goal: A feature I want in my app involves being able to record a ~15 second audio clip of what the user is listening to.  Just general audio output, so it can be part of a YouTube video, a part of an iTunes song, whatever.  (Getting the audio from a single app would be fine too, but it would have to work with at least Safari.)  I also wanted to distribute this app on the Mac Apps Store, so sandboxing is necessary.

Problem: I can not find anything that allows me to record audio output. The closest things I have found are Soundflower and JackOSX.  However, I believe both require to be installed.  And if I recall correctly, installing 3rd party content is a no-go for sandboxed apps in the App Store.

I wish I had more info to give, but I have found very little during my searching.  I don't even know where to start.  I know it's technically possible because of Screenflow, but that doesn't mean it is anywhere NEAR my beginner-ish level of expertise.  Thanks for any info.

Comment: Hello There, Did you find any solution for this? Rookie having same question don't know: where to start from?